# fprintf to print the contents into the file for integers and characters

Tags: c

A buffer with 310 bytes has to be emptied and write the contents of the buffer into a ASCII file when the buffer is full and when I execute the program with the following lines of code, the contents of the file are correctly written with 10 lines and in each line containing 31 Bytes.
buffUSed value is 10 and buffSize is 10 and actSize variable has 30 in it.

```
            if(buffUsed == buffSize)
            { 
              retOpen = createASCIIFile();
              x = 1;
              for(i =0 ;i<(buffUsed*(actSize+1));i++)
              {
                    if(i==(x*31))
                    {
                      fprintf(fPtr,"\n");
                      x++;
                    }               
                    fprintf(fPtr,"%c",buffer[i]);
                 }
              }
```

but the buffer contains characters and integers so when I try to do in the following way the contents written into the file are empty and contains only one line and not 10 lines.

```
if(buffUsed == buffSize)
            { 
              retOpen = createASCIIFile();
              x = 1;
              for(i =0 ;i<(buffUsed*(actSize+1));i++)
              {

                for(i =i ;i<(buffUsed*(actSize+1));i++)
                {
                  if(i==x*(actSize+1))
                  {
                    fprintf(fPtr,"\n");
                    x++;
                  }

                  for(j=i+((buffUsed-1)*(actSize+1)); j<19+((buffUsed-1)*(actSize+1));j++)
                  {
                    fprintf(fPtr,"%c",buffer[j]);
                  }

                  for(k=j;k<23+((buffUsed-1)*(actSize+1));k++)
                  {
                    fprintf(fPtr,"%d",buffer[k]);
                  }

                  for(l=k;l<(actSize+1)+((buffUsed-1)*(actSize+1));l++)
                  {
                    fprintf(fPtr,"%d",buffer[l]);
                  } 
                  i=l-1;
                }     
              }
              retOpen = closeFile();
              fileRename();
            }
          }
```

How can I write into the file with characters and integers. Would be great if someone helps. thanks in advance

Comment: `"12345"` is not the same as `12345`.

Comment: It is printing only a line with 31bytes into the file, but it should print 10line with 31 bytes having characters and numbers into the file

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about, but the buffer cannot contain "characters and integers". Presumably it contains chars, but that depends on the declaration (which you haven't shown).

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I want to write some of the contents of the buffer as character format and some as integer format.